# JaxB and Enum bindings

Tags: java, binding, enums, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to produce a valid xsd for the Oracle Planets example:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }
}
```

When I run it through jaxb-schemagen.jar I get a valid schema, but it does not take into account the **values** passed into the Planet instances above. ie.

> MERCURY(**3.3**, **2.4**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="planet">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="MERCURY"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="VENUS"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="EARTH"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="MARS"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="JUPITER"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="SATURN"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="URANUS"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="NEPTUNE"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Are there any binding examples out there to help produce these values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@XmlEnumValue` annotation to customize the enumeration value that appears in the XML Schema.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html

Comment: Changes enum name, doesn't add a value.  Doesn't seem to work for my problem